# Will Orphaned site in database cause any issues?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

we are having a content database , that is hosting one site collection and one orphaned site collection as well.

Will this orphaned site cause any issues apart from upgrade problems?

Answer (score 1):

Orphaned items normally do not hurt in normal production. You will not be able to create a new site with the URL of the orphaned site. You *might* run into trouble when patching and upgrading.

If you want to get rid of the orphaned site, we need some more information to dig deeper. First question is if the site still exists in the database - get the information with this query against your Content-DB and add the result to your question. Please also mark existing and orphaned SiteURLs (can be anonymized)

```
SELECT s.Id,s.RootWebId,s.Deleted,w.FullUrl 
FROM AllSites as s LEFT JOIN AllWebs as w
WITH (NOLOCK)
ON s.Id = w.SiteId;
```